# What does the inner query in the following SQL query do? What does it mean when two datetime functions are in the min function?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm doing the previous homework assignments of a database systems course at Carnegie Mellon https://15445.courses.cs.cmu.edu/fall2018/homework1/ 
I am stuck on question 4. The correct SQL query on SQLite3 given in the homework solutions is as follows but I am confused regarding strftime and datetime function before the GROUP BY clause and starting from ROUND(SUM...

```
WITH dates AS (SELECT date(start_time) AS tdate 
               FROM trip 
               UNION 
               SELECT date(end_time) AS tdate 
               FROM trip) 
SELECT tdate,
   ROUND(SUM(strftime('%s', MIN(datetime(end_time), datetime(tdate, '+1
     day'))) - strftime('%s', MAX(datetime(start_time), datetime(tdate)))) 
     * 1.0 / (SELECT count(distinct(bike_id)) 
              FROM trip 
              WHERE bike_id <= 100), 4) AS avg_duration 
FROM trip, dates 
WHERE bike_id <= 100 
AND datetime(start_time) < datetime(tdate, '+1 day') 
AND datetime(end_time) > datetime(tdate) 
GROUP BY tdate 
ORDER BY avg_duration DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: What is the "inner query" you are referring to? The `SELECT date(start_time) AS tdate FROM trip 
UNION 
SELECT date(end_time) AS tdate FROM trip` ?

Comment: As Sea Sharp has demonstrated, using whitespace and indentation wisely can very much help making code readable. Consider adopting the habit.

Comment: A database systems course that include implicit joins as a solution? Someone should really update the syllabus there.

Comment: @ZoharPeled not using aliases either.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, I do mean `SELECT date(start_time) AS tdate FROM trip UNION SELECT date(end_time) AS tdate FROM trip`

Comment: I am also confused as to what the datetime and strftime functions do inside the ROUND clause